# Which mysql system variable affects group by clause?

Tags: mysql, performance

I am applying group by on dynamic fields 
Which mysql system variable increases speed?

for example: tmp_table_size or max_heap_table_size or any other...

My table size is 700 MB and explain gives me "Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort"

My query is following:

```
    SELECT 
      IF(
        flag IN ('A', 'B') 
        'featured',
        'normal'
      ) AS package,
      IF(
        flag2 = 'A',
        'group1',
        'group2'
      ) AS group_num,
      COUNT(*) AS total 
    FROM
      mytable
    WHERE publish = 1 
      AND status IN ('on', 'deleted', 'expired',) 
    GROUP BY customized_flag,
      agency_package_status ;
```

Comment: While there are some system variables that will affect execution speed, the most important factor are the indexes. So add one. E.g. `mytable(customized_flag,agency_package_status,publish,status)` or `mytable(publish,customized_flag,agency_package_status)` or something similar (it depends a little bit on your data content). Also be aware that if you have more than 1 row in a group (same values in `customized_flag, agency_package_status`) with different values for `flag` or `flag2`, it's unclear which of these values to use to calculate `package` and `group_num`. (MySQL will use a random row).

Comment: You should not be looking for system variables except as a last resort. The reason for slow query performance is almost invariably to be found within the query itself, or the (possibly missing) indexes it relies on.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that *might* speed up the query is

```
INDEX(publish, status) -- in that order.
```

That would possibly filter down to a small subset of the 700MB.

Your `GROUP BY` is broken -- you will get 'unpredictable' values for `group_num` in the output since it does not appear to be dependent on either `customized_flag` or `agency_package_status`.